# Java parametrized static method with parametrized class member

Tags: java, generics, static

I have a list of parametrized handler objects according to object's class. I try to implement a parametrized factory method which will supply corresponding handler using cashe implemented by Map.
I wrote a code but I receive compiler exception:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyHandler<capture#1-of ? extends
> MyObject> to MyHandler

Please help, how I can achive my goal?

Here is my code:

```
public interface MyHandler<T extends MyObject> {
    
   Map<Class<? extends MyObject>, MyHandler<? extends MyObject>> HANDLERS = new HashMap<>();

   static <E extends MyObject> MyHandler<E> getMyHandler(Class<E> type) {
        return HANDLERS.get(type); // here is the error
    }
}
```

Comment: `MyFactory`? Is this your actual code?

Comment: You absolutely must do an unsafe cast here.  There is no alternative.

Comment: @LouisWasserman is right. While you know that the generic types of the map entries match the generic types of the map values, the compiler doesn't.

Comment: @user16320675 (ii)Since MyHandler is an interface, all its members are static

Comment: @tgdavies It was a typo, I corrected it